# Problem while hosting codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

After hosting the codeigniter project, while I run it I shows me 404 number error.
 please tell me what change I should do?

Comment: You are going to have to give *far* more information for anyone to be able to provide you with useful help.

Answer (score 0):

edit your config file

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://mysite.com/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Checklist

- Make sure your base_url is properly set in config.php
- If its your first time using CodeIgniter, a good practice is to keep index.php included in urls and get a better understanding of the framework
- If you're removing index.php as the index_page in config.php, then make sure you have correct .htacess settings so that your URL's are rewritten properly.
- Make sure the default controller is set properly in config/routes.php. Also make sure the default controller/method that you're calling in your URL actually exists in your code.

Other than the above, it starts to get very specific with how your project is currently configured to provide any help. Please post more specific information if the above doesn't help.